# Fix the way a merge was done in Git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-revert

Here is the situation I'm facing: a development branch was merged in the master. The work done in the branch was great, but the resolution of the conflict was very bad (used --ours)

```
  -x--x--x--M--z--z
           /
  -a--a--a
```

What is in the x and the a is fine, but the problem comes from M. So, ideally, I would like to revert the merge M and merge again, but this can only be done by "reverting the revert", which would not allow me to change the way the merge was done (if I'm not wrong).

How can I do this?

(All the commits have already been pushed and shared, so I would like to avoid resets)

Comment: Is the develop branch still there and in the state it was before the merge ? (i.e. no new commit)

Comment: Yes it is still there, untouched

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of options:

#### A. Fix the original merge

If you want to *undo* the merge and do it again differently, you're going to [rewrite history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), meaning that the SHA-1 hashes of `M` and all the following commits are going to *change*. This could be a problem if you don't have a way to communicate this to everyone who cloned the repository and have potentially already fetched the old commits.

Having said that, you can fix the merge commit by doing an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode).

Assuming `HEAD` is on `master`:

```
x--x--x--M--z--z <- master, HEAD
           /
    a--a--a
```

you can do

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 --preserve-merges
```

to start the rebase from *3 commits before HEAD*, which would be the commit just before the merge commit. The `--preserve-merges` option makes sure that the merge commit itself is available for modification in the *TODO list*. At that point you can mark `M` for `edit` and proceed amending it.

#### B. Make a new commit

If you don't want to rewrite history, the simplest solution would be to simply make a new commit that corrects any errors introduced by the original merge `M`:

```
x--x--x--M--z--z--F <- master, HEAD
           /
    a--a--a
```

where `F` is a *new commit* that compensates for `M` by fixing the problems it introduced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally made it in another way, any opinion on that answer?

Comment: I have a doubt now that I read again your answer. Does the rebase solution actually rewrite history?

Comment: Your approach certainly works but I think it overly complicates history. If you're going to _compensate_ for the errors introduced by `M` with a new merge, you might as well just make a new compensating commit at the top of `master`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, fixing the original merge by rebasing rewrites history starting from the merge commit.

Comment: Thank your for your feedback! Indeed, the result is the same as a new compensating commit in the end. The difference is that I could see in the conflicts which files were affected by the wrong merge strategy instead of having to check the whole commit and search for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I finally figured it out by myself.

My idea is to create a new branch from the master before the problematic merge, recreate (correctly) the merge with the development branch, cherry-pick the commits from the master and finally merge back to the master.

In more details, I create a branch 'Fix' right before the problematic merge and merge the development branch in the new branch. I can then merge the two branches as I want.

```
-x--x--x--M--z--z
         X
-a--a--a  \
         \ \
           M'
```

Then, I cherry-pick the commits from the master

```
-x--x--x--M--z--z
         X
-a--a--a  \
         \ \
           M'--z--z
```

And finally, I merge back the 'Fix' branch on the master. This will create another set of conflicts (because of the two merges) which need to be fixed (but one can almost surely keep the changes from the 'Fix' branch). In the end, the master is in the state that I wanted it to be.

```
-x--x--x--M--z--z-----N
         X           /
-a--a--a  \         /
         \ \       /
           M'--z--z
```

At least, that worked in my case.

Comment: It's a lot easier if you make a commit where you merge `M` into `M'` first but with the tree of files at the same state of `M'` using something like a `merge -n ...; reset M' -- .; commit` sequence and then merge that commit into the latest state of the current branch. This was you are not resolving conflicts that might be between `M` and `M'` (which you want to resolve in favour of `M'`) and might be between `M'` and the latest state of  the branch which you probably want to resolve "fairly".

Comment: @CharlesBailey You're right, that can probably be made shorter and easier!